# Установка библиотеки gd в контейнере

Tags: php, docker, gd, dockerfile

Имеется docker контейнер `php:7.1-fpm` на котором крутится lumen. Появилась необходимость установить библиотеку `maatwebsite/excel` для выгрузки информации в Excel, однако `composer require maatwebsite/excel` выполняемый в контейнере ругается на отсутствие библиотеки `gd`. Попытался установить ее и прописать в `php.ini` следующим образом:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
# For gd
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng12-dev \
    libxpm-dev \
    libvpx-dev
RUN docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
RUN docker-php-ext-enable gd
RUN echo 'extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/gd.so' >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
```

(+ всевозможными комбинациями типа `extension=gd`, `docker-php-ext-install gd` и тд)

Результат не изменился, композер ругается на отсутствие библиотеки gd.

Всвязи с этим вопрос: Как можно корректно установить gd в контейнере для php7.1 fpm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавь в инстал `libgd-dev`

Мой работающий конфиг в одном из проектов:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev mysql-client php-soap libxml2-dev libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
        libgd-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt pdo_mysql soap gd exif
```